# Loss files when use getExternalStorageDirectory

Tags: android

I am store files in subdirectory of getExternalStorageDirectory (memory card).
But sometimes users write to me that they are losing files.
why users lose their files? Maybe they remove sdcard? But if they have no sdcard?

Answer (score 0):

the user or anyone(other app) can remove files even if the externalStorage is partition on device memory else they remove the sdCard.